# Rails: Rubymine: GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I can't seem to figure out how to commit my files to GitHub.

I am using RubyMine 4.5 on the MAC

I have git set up locally

I have a private account on GitHub

From the RubyMine Preferences, I have my GitHub credentials properly set up (and acknowledged as such by RubyMine), but it did not give me an option to select a repository on GitHub.

How do I commit file to the GitHub repository? There are too many CVS and Git menu items in RubyMine.

PS: I've read the online help sections (the only thing available to me), and I followed the instructions in the GitHub integration, but the directory I'm trying to commit is failing to push to GitHub, with RubyMine telling me that there was nothing to commit. This is the first time I use RubyMine for GitHub. Nothing about this on StackOverflow.

Comment: Command 9 takes me to the changes window. No Unversioned files line and the Default is empty. I tried to create a changelist, but it's empty and none of the options in the changes window let me add files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I think I've recreated your situation locally and it appears that RubyMine has terrible support for managing remotes. If you create a Git repository locally, then (separately) create a repository on GitHub, there's no obvious way to marry the two from within RubyMine.

Basically, you need to set up GitHub as a remote for your local repository from the shell, and once that's done then RubyMine will be able to push as normal.

***Please note that the below instructions assume you want to overwrite your GitHub repository with the full history from your local repository -- If your GitHub repository has data that you do not want to lose, do not execute these commands! See Below.***

Open up Terminal:

```
cd /path/to/my/project/root
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/yourrepo.git
git push -u origin +master
```

Now, RubyMine should be able to push to your GitHub repository via `VCS > Git > Push`

If your GitHub repository has already been committed to and you don't want to lose those changes, you'll need to either create a new GitHub repo or clone your GitHub repo into another folder and merge your local repository into the clone.

This can be avoided entirely if you're trying to push your existing local repository to a **new** GitHub repo: Simply use the `VCS > Import into Version Control > Share project on GitHub` option and use the dialog to create a new GitHub repository.

Comment: I forget to add that what you suggested above worked, although I did try that same syntax myself, with no success a couple of days ago. Perhaps I was still missing something. This is of course done outside RubyMine. I posted something that I think is a big in RubyMine on their dev discussion forum, a few hours ago, but so far I have not heard back.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is enough to set up your local branch to track the remote branch, no need to overwrite the history at all.